# Rector PHP || RemoveUnusedForeachKeyRector

Tags: php, rector

Rector is applying a rule RemoveUnusedForeachKeyRector at a certain loop in my file. However, I do use the `key` later in my code. Is there a way I can enforce rector not to apply this rule ?

Comment: First of all, if you think this is a bug, you should search the issue tracker for it, because if not yet reported, you should report it. Second, if already reported, it will likely also document the workaround, which is what you ask for. third, and apart from these two, consult the rector manual how to configure rules, e.g. disabling a rule.